# Using Scrapy to get search results from a forum

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

can anybody help me?

I am trying to use Scrapy to collect the results for searching for a keyword (eg. 朝鲜）on this [forum](http://bbs1.people.com.cn/board/1.html). When I use the search bar, I get a list of results, but then trying to scrape these with Scrapy based on the result page url (http://bbs1.people.com.cn/quickSearch.do?field=title&threadtype=1&content=%E6%9C%9D%E9%B2%9C) doesn't seem to work. It usually gives me a time out. Is there any way to resolve this?

If I try to scrape the whole page of search results, using the [address](http://bbs1.people.com.cn/quickSearch.do?field=title&threadtype=1&content=%E6%9C%9D%E9%B2%9C) at the top. Page looks like:

[image]

But then when I return to it:

[image]

I can't figure out why....Huge thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Answer (score 0):

hi friend i do have a answer for your question:

first you will have to fetch the info from the page using the code

fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/")

and then you will need to extract the information so you can view it and then set arrays to find the certain key word you did love to get:

For more info or for better understanding and for the remaining code you can got to the website: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/web-scraping-in-python-using-scrapy/

Comment: Thanks, but when I use - `fetch('url')` and then `view(response)` - the page loads in the browser differently, and doesn't deliver the search results anymore. That means the scrape also hasn't got these in the code. I updated the post above with screenshots to illustrate.